# Powershell: "Failed to update help"

Tags: powershell

Running PowerShell as administrator, `Update-Help` fails with a long list of modules. So I'm guessing the help server cannot be reached. How can I tell which server is unreachable?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Update-Help
Update-Help : Failed to update Help for the module(s) 'ActiveDirectory, AppBackgroundTask, AppLocker, AppvClient, Appx, AssignedAccess, BestPractices, BitLocker, 
BitsTransfer, BranchCache, CimCmdlets, ClusterAwareUpdating, Defender, DirectAccessClientComponents, Dism, DnsClient, DnsServer, FailoverClusters, GroupPolicy, 
HgsClient, International, iSCSI, IscsiTarget, ISE, Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive, Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics, 
Microsoft.PowerShell.Host, Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts, Microsoft.PowerShell.Management, Microsoft.PowerShell.ODataUtils, 
Microsoft.PowerShell.Operation.Validation, Microsoft.PowerShell.Security, Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility, Microsoft.WSMan.Management, MMAgent, MsDtc, MSMQ, NetAdapter, 
NetEventPacketCapture, NetLbfo, NetLldpAgent, NetNat, NetQos, NetSecurity, NetSwitchTeam, NetTCPIP, NetworkController, NetworkControllerDiagnostics, 
PackageManagement, PnpDevice, PowerShellGet, PrintManagement, ProcessMitigations, Provisioning, PSDesiredStateConfiguration, PSReadline, PSScheduledJob, PSWorkflow, 
PSWorkflowUtility, RemoteAccess, RemoteDesktop, ScheduledTasks, SecureBoot, ShieldedVMDataFile, ShieldedVMTemplate, StartLayout, Storage, StorageQoS, StorageReplica, 
TLS, TroubleshootingPack, TrustedPlatformModule, UEV, UpdateServices, WebAdministration, WindowsDeveloperLicense, WindowsErrorReporting, WindowsSearch, 
WindowsUpdate, WindowsUpdateProvider' with UI culture(s) {en-US} : Unable to connect to Help content. The server on which Help content is stored might not be 
available. Verify that the server is available, or wait until the server is back online, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-Help
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Update-Help], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnableToConnect,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.UpdateHelpCommand


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                  
----                           -----                                                                                                                                  
PSVersion                      5.1.16299.666                                                                                                                          
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                
BuildVersion                   10.0.16299.666                                                                                                                         
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                        
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                    
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                    
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                                                                

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole( [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]"Administrator")

True
```

Followed some advice from the following, but problem not yet solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834452/powershell-fails-with-update

Edit: In reference to the "duplicate question" please see that question and answer. It does not parallel my question in that I was asking how to know the site that is not available for the update help to function. The other question was asking about specific modules, and their answer suggested correctly perhaps those modules don't have help. In my case, it's pretty clear most of the modules have help, I just can't access them and am asking how to know on which sites the help files exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update-help fails to update two modules](https://superuser.com/questions/1286844/update-help-fails-to-update-two-modules)

Comment: @Ramhound thanks but nope; see my edit. I'm asking how to determine the site of the help if and when it does exist; the site to which the fetch is failing.